# Are there any consequences if I faint?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I got stung by bees twice today and the second time I apparently fainted, which brought me back to my house. Are there any other penalties to fainting that I have to worry about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no consequences other than being relocated to your house.

Comment: If you're visiting an island you simply just go back to the dock of the island you are at.